# What is the Rust equivalent of JavaScript's spread operator for arrays?

Tags: arrays, vector, rust

In JavaScript, there is an operator called the spread operator that allows you to combine arrays very concisely.

```js
let x = [3, 4];
let y = [5, ...x]; // y is [5, 3, 4]
```

Is there a way to do something like this in Rust?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just need `y` to be iterable, you can do:

```
let x = [3,4];
let y = [5].iter().chain(&x);
```

If you need it to be indexable, then you'll want to collect it into a vector.

```
let y: Vec<_> = [5].iter().chain(&x).map(|&x|x).collect();
```

Comment: This works. Are there any significant performance implications in doing it this way?

Comment: @laptou: I doubt it. But you can compare the output assembly here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=e67df670ea90e0aae9471112336337ed

Comment: @BenjaminLindley they defenitely will be since array is created on stack, and Vec is a heap-allocated structure.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: What are you comparing it to? I assumed we were comparing it to Ijedrz solution, which also uses a vector. Do you have a method that doesn't?

Comment: I was comparing with manual implementation. It could be written as method then const generics gets stabilized.

Answer (score 7):

[Rust's arrays have a fixed length](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html), so there is no way of just combining them together; the usual way to achieve this result would be to have a mutable vector and to [extend it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend_from_slice) with a slice:

```
fn main() {
    let x = [3, 4];
    let mut y = vec![5];
    y.extend_from_slice(&x);

    println!("{:?}", y); // [5, 3, 4]
}
```

Comment: So there is no concise way to: append `x` or `&x[..]` to the vector in the same line as `vec![5]`, then do something with the result before assigning to `y`?

Comment: @laptou references alone can only point to an existing value (for slices, this would be a contiguous section of values `[T]`), so no new values can be appended through a slice. Dynamic manipulation of sequences is usually performed with vectors, so that they may own that memory.

Comment: @laptou as far as I remember there was once a suggestion to implement `Add` between `Vec<T>` and `&[T]`, as it is already possible with `String` and `&[str]`, but it was rejected.

Comment: @E_net4 I understand, but since these are primitive values that implement `Copy` (in my specific use case, I am trying to concatenate a `Vec<u8>` with `[u8; 2]` in a single line) I was hoping there might be a shortcut.

Comment: @laptou yep, found it: [Implement Add for Vec](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/38573).

Comment: @laptou Indeed, appending values to an existing vector is possible, although there is currently no standard syntax for doing that in a single line. `Extend` is a suitable trait to use here once you already built a vector somewhere.

Comment: With that said, Rust arrays having a fixed length would not be an impediment to array spreading as part of the language's syntax, so long as the inputs and outputs were also arrays. I wouldn't be surprised if someone already proposed such a syntax into an RFC or just built a macro to achieve a similar effect.

Answer (score 6):

You can build a `Vec` from as many pieces as you want using [`[T]::concat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.concat):

```rust
let x = [3, 4];
let y = [&[5], &x[..]].concat();
// gives vec![5, 3, 4]
```